# Is it a standard thing to challenge someone to best of 7 Games of Pool?

Tags: the-oc

In the OC S02e12, Ryan challenges Caleb to pool for Caleb to respect his and Lindsays relationship. When he approaches Lindsay, before challenging Caleb, he tells her it will take a few hours, and when he then does challenege Caleb, Caleb suggests they play "best of 7" which would indeed take a few hours, as if Ryan knew Caleb would suggest that or something similar.

So, my question is, is it a standard thing to challenge someone to best of 7 games of pool? Or did the show do something strange here? Because best of 7 seems like a lot.

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to be a question at all. I have edited it.

Comment: Depends... different pool games take different amounts of time. Nine-ball is pretty fast and it really needs to be played more than once to allow for fairness... Eight-ball can be slow or fast depending on the skill of the players and how much they play defense... but, again, one game doesn't give much of a chance if someone gets a break-and-run.

Comment: @AJ edit appreciated! Though, I didn't think that question titles needed to specifically have a question in them, as long as the question itself contains a valid question

Comment: @Catija they were playing 8 ball, if that makes a difference

Comment: They don't *have* to have a question but *I* personally prefer it. I'm not a fan of the statement-style at times, and I think this was a good edit, personally.

Answer (score 1):

Is it "standard"?  No.  Certainly more than 1 game is almost always played to compensate for fluke wins and determine who is more skilled.  So, a minimum of 3 games is the norm.  "Best of Seven" was probably used because the terminology exists in mainstream lexicon; this is how professional Hockey, Baseball and Basketball championships are determined.

Also, if the show needed to account for a few hours then best-of-seven is a lot more believable than best-of-three.  Even so, a best-of-seven tournament probably wouldn't take more than two hours, as that allows for each game to last approximately 15 minutes with time to re-rack in between.  That's a pretty long game for anyone with any skill at all, especially if they're playing 8-Ball.  Pro 8-Ball games usually only last about 5 minutes.

Comment: I think a lot of the time is spent exchanging thinly veiled insults, plus Caleb might have been drinking. I never thought of the hockey comparison!